# Query which compares two fields with $lookup

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

users collection

```
[   
    {name: "alex", age: 25, surname: "brown"},
    {name: "tom", age: 34, surname: "gray"},
    {name: "alex", age: 65, surname: "red"},
    {name: "alex", age: 32, surname: "yellow"}
]
```

participation collection

```
[   
    {name: "alex", age: 32}
]
```

I want to get only one document's details whose name is `alex` and age is `32`.

What have I done so far?

```
db.participation.aggregate([
   {$lookup: "users" , foreignField: "name" , localField: "name", as: "document"},
   {$unwind: "document"},
   {$match: {age: "$document.age"}}
])
```

But this returns nothing, the returned array is empty.

So how should I create the query?

Comment: You can try `{$match: {"document.age":32,"document.name": "alex"}}`

Comment: Ehehe thank you but these `age` and `name` fields are dynamic that's why I try this way.

Comment: oh I see. You can try `$redact`.

Comment: What is your mongod version?

Comment: my mongod version is  `v3.4.2`

Comment: @mmu3647 I've already posted an answer

Comment: thank you for your answer but actually i didn't understand why this query returns empty array, can you explain?

Comment: Do you mean your initial query?

Comment: yes and also i didn't exactly understand your answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143305/discussion-between-mmu36478-and-s-s).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is in MongoDB 3.4 using using the `$replaceRoot` pipeline operator to reshape the document. Also you shouldn't use `$unwind` here.

```
[
   { "$match": { "name":"alex", "age": 32 } },
   {
      "$lookup": {
         "from": "user",
         "foreignField": "name",
         "localField": "name",
         "as": "result"
      }
   },
   {
      "$replaceRoot" :{
         "newRoot": {
            "$arrayElemAt": [
               {
                  "$filter": {
                     "input": "$result",
                     "cond": {
                        "$and": [
                            { "$eq": [ "$$this.age", 32 ] },
                            { "$eq": [ "$$this.name", "alex" ] }
                        ]
                     }
                  }
               },
               0
            ]
         }
      }
   }
]
```

Comment: i am not sure whether the first stage should be the match stage or not. he needs to match the criteria based on the users collection not directly from participant if you run the query on the participant collection. so after unwinding the result array, a match is needed i think.

Comment: @Hakan I put `$match` first because FWIU OP is trying to retrieve information of the same user. (name and age). I may be wrong here